# How do I rearrange this equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm solving an op-amp question and have simplified the variables for convenience :

Rearrange
$$\frac{a+b}{c} = \frac{b-d}{e}$$

To get
$$b = \frac{ae + cd}{c + e}.$$

Can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use distributive law of division, that is$$\frac{a+b}{c} = \frac{b-d}{e}\implies\dfrac{a}{c} + \dfrac{b}{c} = \dfrac{b}{e} -\dfrac{d}{e}$$
$$\implies \dfrac{a}{c}+\dfrac{d}{e}=\dfrac{b}{e}-\dfrac{b}{c}$$ 
$$\implies \dfrac{ae+dc}{ce}=\dfrac{bc-be}{ce}$$
$$\implies ae+dc=bc-be$$
$$\implies b(c-e)=ae+dc$$
$$\implies b=\dfrac{ae+dc}{c-e}$$

Answer (score 2):

The answer you quote has a slight mistake in it.

Multiply through by $ce$:
$$ea+eb=cb-cd.$$
Collect the $b$ terms:
$$b(e-c)=-cd-ea.$$
Divide by $e-c$:
$$b=-\frac{cd+ea}{e-c}=\frac{cd+ea}{c-e}.$$